# how to pass a value (href to be precise) in a cucumber feature file

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir

I have a cucumber feature file which looks like below,

Given I am logged in to the console

- When I navigate to the "href1" page
- When I navigate to the "href2" page
- When I navigate to the "href3" page
- When I navigate to the "href4" page

Instead on writing the when command 4 times I want to know if I can somehow pass the value of the href and call it in the when statement.

I have a step definition which looks like this :

```
When(/^I navigate to the "(.*)" page$/) do |navigation_link|
   @browser.link(:href => navigation_link).when_present.click
end
```

Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple options to do it:

a) If you need to test that you can navigate to each of the pages independtly, you can use a `Scenario Outline` like:

```
Scenario Outline: Test navigation
  Given I am logged in to the console
  When I navigate to the "<href>" page
Examples:
  |href         |
  |<actual_url1>|
  |....         |
  |<actual_url4>|
```

In this case, your step doesn't need to be modified, and should work as is.

b) If you need to navigate to the pages in a dependent manner, i.e., reaching page 4 requires you to follow through page1 -> page2 ->... page X -> page 4, you can use a `table` like:

```
Scenario: Test navigation
  Given I am logged in to the console
  When I navigate through the following pages: 
  |<actual_url1>|
  |....         |
  |<actual_url4>|
```

And then in your step definition:

```
When(/^i navigate through the following pages:$/) do |table|
   table.raw.each do |navigation_link|
     @browser.link(:href => navigation_link.join).when_present.click
   end
end
```

(Read more on tables & outlines here: http://cukes.info/step-definitions.html)

Though, I wouldn't suggest using either of them if you just want to check that you can navigate to page4. I'd rather create the step to only navigate to page 4, and within that step's definition-> take the url_paths in variables (much better to have in a separate paths file and load from there)-> navigate to other pre-requisite pages-> Navigate to the final page.

This way you would only describe the behaviour and not literal navigation points.

Comment: i tried the Second method, but it throws an error as below     Scenario:
Given i am logged in to the console
When i navigate through the following pages:
|/AirWatch/#/Hub|                             |#/Menu/Hub/ReportsAnalytics|
|#/Menu/Hub/ReportsAnalytics/Reports|
|/AirWatch/#/Report/List/AllReports|
 expected one of [String, Regexp], got [</AirWatch/#/Hub>"]:Array (TypeError) ./features/step_definitions/Report.rb:45:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
./features/step_definitions/Report.rb:44:in `each'

Comment: Sorry, yes you would get them as arrays. Just convert them to a string as :href => navigation_link.join (Updated my answer with the same).

Comment: Gr8, Cheers. Please accept the answer if it worked. Also, give a thought to  the point I mentioned in the end. It might help to make your tests more reliable and independent.

Comment: sure, thanks for all the help. Just wanted to know if one table in a feature file can be used multiple times in the same feature file and also if it can be used in a different feature file.

Comment: You can use tables as many times as you want in the same / different feature files. But if they are similar scenarios, club them together using scenario outlines, along with your tables.

Comment: ok, can you tell me how to use a CSV for the above mentioned scenario.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45390/discussion-between-xammy-and-nandish-shetty)